Insert DOM element on the specific index of parent DIV
There is a DIV in Angular template:
<div #parent [innerHTML]="content"></div>
and in .ts file
let content = 'test1 test2 test3'
Now I'm creating new DIV:
const newDiv = this.renderer.createElement('div') as HTMLDivElement
newDiv.innerHTML = 'plug' 
newDiv.addEventListener('click'......)
Goal is to have inside #parent:
test1 <div>plug</div> test2 test3
and new div should have working listener.
How?
Manipulating innerHTML as string directly is not a solution: div exists but it is invisible for Angular engine.

The content of your parent div is just a text node, and you can't directly insert a div element into that. You will need to split this text node up into two parts, and then insert the new child div in between.

The original content of parent div is html and is variable and Angular is now aware of its DOM structure. For example:
Home dogcattree apple
and I want new div to appear between 'tree' and 'apple'.
How to split it?

You need to find the text node containing tree apple, and then either replace that with a new text node, your div, and another new text node; or you "truncate" the existing node (by assigning tree as the nodeValue, and then you insert your new div, and a new text node containing apple, after the original text node.

Or use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text/splitText, that can help you split your one existing text node, into two text node siblings. And then you just need to insert your new child div after the first text node.

If you're working in Angular, why not just use the Angular mechanisms for working with dynamic content? What are you actually trying to achieve here?

I'm using online text editor (angular-editor). User is editing text, so editor creates html structure which is not "connected" to angular. Goal is to detect specified structures and do something with them: for instance replace in-text footnotes with nice popup, or list footnotes under the text automatically, detect links and show miniatures etc.

Ugly solution:
//have some dynamic html which angular engine is not aware of:
let content = 'apple tree or <span>any other <b>dynamic</b></span> text'
//create temporary div or any other DOM element by string:
let tempInjector = '<div id="ref1"></div>'
// make new string and put the injecor into old string using brutal text/non-dom methods:
let nc = content.substring(0, 5) + tempInjector + content.substring(5, content.length)

// create DOM object in proper way with angular renderer, and assign some listener+content:
const newEl = this.renderer.createElement('div') as HTMLDivElement;
this.renderer.listen(newEl, 'click', (event) => {console.log('this is angular aware DOM');})
newEl.innerHTML = '[ANGULAR AWARE OBJECT]'

//(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) this is imporant step!
this.cdr.detectChanges()

// now get the "injector" as dom object using id:
const el = document.getElementById('ref1')
if (el) {
    // insert Angular object after "injector"
    el?.insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', newEl)
    // then remove injector.
    el.remove()
}

//update variable connected with html:
this.content = nc

Done. Now your angular aware DOM node is inside html with working listener and other angular-like things.
